# Password hashing is not reliable

Tags: php, hash

I am using the following steps to create a hash that is to be stored in my DB:

```
$ret=randStrGen(100).time();
$gtch = chunk_split($a,1,'.;l89b_-');
$Thm = hash_hmac('sha512', $gtch, file_get_contents('serial.txt'));
$hash =crypt($Thm,sprintf('$2y$%02d$',4).randStrGen(22).$ret);
```

The main problem is that the variable `$hash` does not always return a hashed value, and instead it returns `*0`. so it is not reliable, and I have no idea why this happens?

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

from crypt() documentation:

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$",
>   "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters
>   from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this
>   range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string.

My randStrGen() which is used as salt, is actually using non-alphanumeric characters, and this was the cause of the problem. Thanks every one.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're trying to hash a password, you should probably just use `password_hash`

Comment: This is very dangerous code you have here. Do not **wrap your own** string hashing, use the built in methods, they are more secure.

Comment: Since the title is "Password hashing": When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

As you already discovered, the salt has to be in a specific format, not all characters are allowed for BCrypt, that's the reason for the errors.

Another problem with your code is the cost factor, which is way too low to be an effective protection for the passwords. Currently it should be at least about 10.

That said, you absolutely should use the built-in functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and password_verify(), they use best practices to generate a safe salt and the other difficult parts like backwards compatibility with future algorithms.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```